# How to populate current error message in `xsl:message` in XSLT 2.0 or 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to print run time error message here is input i can use any version of XSLT 2.0 or 3.0:

```
<transaction>
    <actual_premium>3200000000</actual_premium>
    <actual_premium>3200000000</actual_premium>
</transaction>
```

XSLT i am trying:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Premium" select="/transaction/actual_premium"/>
    <root>

        <xsl:try>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($Premium, '###,###,###')"/>
            <xsl:catch>
                <!-- Here i want to print error message A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:format-number() -->
                <xsl:message select="current()"/>
            </xsl:catch>
        </xsl:try> 

    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Error message `A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:format-number()` should be populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2 has no `try/catch`, as for XSLT 3, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#try-catch-examples on how to use `$err:code` and/or `$err:description` in the namespace `xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"`

```
 <xsl:try>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($Premium, '###,###,###')"/>
    <xsl:catch>
      <xsl:message>
          Error code: <xsl:value-of select="$err:code"/>
          Reason: <xsl:value-of select="$err:description"/>
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:catch>
  </xsl:try>
```

and of course the full description in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#try-catch of all the variables available within `xsl:catch`.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you i am unable to find how to use `$err:code` and/or `$err:description`.

Comment: Does the example I have given not demonstrate that? Or the ones in the XSLT 3 spec? The XSLT 3 fiddle site I have is not set up to display `xsl:message` but removing that and directly outputting the values at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcg/1 also in my view demonstrates the use of those variables inside of `xsl:catch`, even if not in the context of your original request, i.e. inside of `xsl:message`. But that should work as well if you don't work in a restricted environment of the fiddle web app but with an XSLT IDE or with Saxon from the command line.