# Is it possible to store the parser error message in variable using xslt2.0 or xslt 3.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am doing transform xml file using `xslt` and I want to display the error message of `xslt` parser in an element

> Note: Error message should be original of parser message

Comment: What do you mean by parser error? Parsing fase is done before you get an XML instance to process. I think there are tools for generating XML response from parsing.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you consider an error message of an "xslt parser"? Is the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55356168/how-to-populate-current-error-message-in-xslmessage-in-xslt-2-0-or-3-0 helpful? It is not about XML input parsing but it shows how to capture XSLT run-time errors in XSLT 3 with `xsl:try/xsl:catch` and you can of course use it on a call to `doc` as well: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcg/2

Comment: Thanks @Martin to understand me your given link is useful to me and I wanted exactly that output

Thank you once again

Comment: @sunilk, I have put the code from the referenced link example into an answer so you can accept it to indicate your question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a way to capture XML parsing errors of the primary input document to an `apply-templates` based XSLT 3 transformation but in general XSLT 3 with `xsl:try/xsl:catch` allows you to capture and handle run-time errors, so assuming you can organize the rest of your code (for instance by using a named template as the starting point) to load/parse any XML documents with the `doc` or `document` function then you can use `try/catch` to handle parsing errors. An example is https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcg/2

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>

     <xsl:try>
        <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="doc('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/master/xslt/2019/test2019032601.xml')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($doc1//item)"/>
        <xsl:catch>Error code: <xsl:value-of select="$err:code"/>
    Reason: <xsl:value-of select="$err:description"/>
        </xsl:catch>
      </xsl:try>

    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which, depending on your needs, can also be reduced to directly use the relevant XPath expression with the `select` attribute of the `xsl:try` element e.g. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcg/3

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>

     <xsl:try select="count(doc('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/master/xslt/2019/test2019032601.xml'))">
        <xsl:catch>Error code: <xsl:value-of select="$err:code"/>
    Reason: <xsl:value-of select="$err:description"/>
        </xsl:catch>
      </xsl:try>

    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please don't raise separate problems in a comment or in an answer to a previous question, post new question for the new, separate issue. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#result-document-restrictions for the restrictions on the use of `xsl:result-document`, `xsl:function` is one of the elements defined there to now allow the use of `xsl:result-document`.